# Display value of Resource without Label or Literal control

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

How do I display the value of a resource without a ASP.NET control, i.e. I want to avoid this:

```
<asp:Label text="<%$ Resources: Messages, ThankYouLabel %>" id="label1" runat="server" />
```

Instead I would prefer to do just this in my .aspx pages:

```
<%$ Resources: Messages, ThankYouLabel %>
```

... but I can’t, a parser error is thrown:

```
Literal expressions like '<%$ Resources: Messages, ThankYouLabel %>' are not allowed.
Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Messages, ThankYouLabel %>" /> instead.
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `Literal` as suggested?

Comment: It bloats viewstate and I want to trim the pages to the absolute minimum. I also think it increases readability if I can skip the extra controls when really I don't need them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149948.aspx) instead:

```
<asp:Label text='<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "ThankYouLabel") %>' 
     id="label1" 
     runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible. you have to use atleast `Literal`, Another option is to use `GetGlobalResurceObject`, so that you can use directly in a page.

```
<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "ThankYouLabel")%>
```

Answer (score 4):

In code behind You can Use

```
`GetLocalResourceObject("YourKeyInLocalResource")`
```

and also

```
`GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResourceFileName", "YourResourceKey")`
```

and then use a simple aspnet variable in your Asp.net Markup like  <%= Resourcevalue %>

The you can assign your resource value to your Aspnet Variable like

```
Resourcevalue = GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResourceFileName", "YourResourceKey").ToString();
```

Comment: Just as basic '<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Messages", "ThankYouLabel") %>' is really what I need. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another method is :-

```
<asp:Label text='<%= Resources.Messages.ThankYouLabel %>' 
     id="label1" 
     runat="server" />
```